# Match first parenthesis with Python

Tags: python, regex

From a string such as

```
70849   mozilla/5.0(linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn)applewebkit/534.30(khtml,likegecko)version/4.0mobilesafari/534.30
```

I want to get the first parenthesized content `linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn`.

My code looks like this:

```
s=r'70849   mozilla/5.0(linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn)applewebkit/534.30(khtml,likegecko)version/4.0mobilesafari/534.30'
re.search("(\d+)\s.+\((\S+)\)", s).group(2)
```

but the result is the last brackets' contents `khtml,likegecko`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you have is the *greedy dot matching `.+` pattern*. It grabs the whole string you have, and then backtracks, yielding one character from the right at a time, trying to accommodate for the subsequent patterns. Thus, it matches the *last* parentheses.

You can use

```
^(\d+)\s[^(]+\(([^()]+)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wP0fK3/2). Here, the `[^(]+` restricts the matching to the characters other than `(` (so, it cannot grab the whole line up to the end) and get to the first pair of parentheses.

Pattern expalantion:

- `^` - string start (**NOTE**: If the number appears not at the start of the string, remove this `^` anchor)
- `(\d+)` -  Group 1: 1 or more digits
- `\s` - a whitespace (if it is not a required character, it can be removed since the subsequent *negated character class* will match the space)
- `[^(]+` - 1+ characters other than `(`
- `\(`  - a literal `(`
- `([^()]+)` - Group 2 matching 1+ characters other than `(` and `)`
- `\)`- closing `)`.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4cZIEtEvccRdQfUE)

Here is the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/aXSvrg):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(\d+)\s[^(]+\(([^()]+)\)')
test_str = "70849   mozilla/5.0(linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn)applewebkit/534.30(khtml,likegecko)version/4.0mobilesafari/534.30"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# or using re.search if the number is not at the beginning of the string
m = re.search(r'(\d+)\s[^(]+\(([^()]+)\)', test_str)
if m:
    print("Number: {0}\nString: {1}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2)))
# [('70849', 'linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn')]
# Number: 70849
# String: linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn
```

Comment: It works! Why My `(\d+)\s\(([^()]*)\)' failed returns null  @Wiktor

Comment: Please see my explanations: your pattern contained a greedy dot matching pattern that skipped the first parentheses getting to the last ones instead.

Comment: I know greedy impact! `(\d+)\s(([^()]*))` this didn't return the number ,use group(1). But yours works

Comment: Just FYI: if you remove `^` then you will have to use `re.search`, and access the groups #1 and #2. `findall` works because the regex is anchored at the start of the string.

Comment: I have String like `mi3cmiui/5.11.13` and `mi1sbuild/imm76d` I want to get two groups like <mi,3c>and <mi,1s>. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated class `\(([^)]*)\)` to match anything between `(` and `)`:

```
>>> s=r'70849  mozilla/5.0(linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn)applewebkit/534.30(khtml,likegecko)version/4.0mobilesafari/534.30'

>>> m = re.search(r"(\d+)[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)", s)
>>> print m.group(1)
70849
>>> print m.group(2)
linux;u;android4.2.1;zh-cn
```

Comment: You must have wanted to say *negated character class* (`[^)]`) instead of a  *negation regex*. I think `r'\(([^()]*)\)'` is safer though, as it won't capture any "wild" `(` between the first `(` and the closest `)`.

Comment: @anubhava If I want to get the first number 70849 `(\d+)\s\(([^()]*)\)` use group(1) right?

Comment: No, that is not correct. There is no subpattern to go from `\s` to `(`.

Comment: Yes I was editing my answer and replied to John at the same time and didn't notice missing `[^(]*` in his regex :)